# Can any other characters besides Ganondorf play Home Run contest with out a bat?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

In Super Smash Bros Brawl and Super Smash Bros 4, Ganondorf has been able to play Home Run Contest without needed the Home Run bat, thanks to his Reverse Warlock Punch. But, are there any other characters that do not need a Home Run Bat to get over a decent score (1000 FT) in SSB4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not really. Ganon is the only real character who can do a decent job without the bat. Charizard is probably the second best because of his power, but you can only get around 350 feet or so.

[Here's a video of it for reference.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xuIqWVNxVYc)

Answer (score 0):

With version 1.0.8 comes the costs-money DLC character of Roy. Roy can get over 5,000ft easy peasy. Just do a bunch of f-smashes and f-tilts, and when the clock strikes 4, start charging Flare Blade (neutral special). Just when the clock hits zero, the move should detonate for ~50% damage and massive knockback.